# Downloading file from external api in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, model-view-controller, txtextcontrol

I am new to using APIs on laravel. I read through  PHP GuzzleHttp, but i couldnt comprehend how to corelate it with ReportingCloud. I am trying to use
ReportingCloud Docs from https://docs.reporting.cloud/docs/chapter/introduction/whatisreportingcloud . Having followed the documentation, on https://docs.reporting.cloud/docs/chapter/introduction/first page shows  generation a pdf version of invoice. i still dont get the code behind downloading of the pdf file. I tried checking if my template file exist which shows postive. i try using https://docs.reporting.cloud/docs/endpoint/document/merge on merging data to your template and it works fine.
my problem is how to get those files downloaded on my computer

Comment: Did you mean https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#storing-files?

Comment: No.. I don't mean that. I have used dompdf but reportingcloud have better features than it. I want to use it for eporting customizer files of different formats